# TLE issue in java

Tags: java

Given an array A of N positive numbers. The task is to find the position where equilibrium first occurs in the array. Equilibrium position in an array is a position such that the sum of elements below it is equal to the sum of elements after it.

Input:
The first line of input contains an integer T, denoting the number of test cases. Then T test cases follow. First line of each test case contains an integer N denoting the size of the array. Then in the next line are N space separated values of the array A.

Output:
For each test case in a new  line print the position at which the elements are at equilibrium if no equilibrium point exists print -1.

```
static int output[];
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); 
    output = new int[t];
    for(int testcase = 0 ; testcase<t ; testcase++)
    {
        //output[testcase]=new StringBuffer();
        int size = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        String input = br.readLine();
        String[] arr = input.split(" ");
        int[] intArr = new int[arr.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            intArr[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
        }
        output[testcase] = getEquilibrium(intArr);
    }
    for(int j = 0 ; j<t ; j++)
    {
        System.out.println(output[j]);
    }
}
static int getEquilibrium(int array[] )
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++)
    {
        int a = 0,b = 0;
        for(int j = i-1 ; j >= 0 ; j--)
        {
            a +=array[j];
        }
        for(int k = i+1 ; k < array.length ; k++ )
        {
            b +=array[k];
        }
        if(a == b)
            return ++i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Here at SO, we can help you to solve specific problems in your code. In order to do this, we need you to show us a specific problem you are having. We don't, in general, write your code for you.

Comment: Please don't link to a picture of your code. Add the code snippet that you are having problems with into your post.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two for loops which makes the complexity as O(n^2). The constraints might be up to 10^9 (question lacks constraints) and so you are getting TLE.
Anyway, the solution was not correct as the logic used fails at many conditions.

**Efficient approach - O(n)**

my code link: https://paste.ee/p/2nDJ3
Please comment down if you find any issues.
Hope so this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach for O(n)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int T = input.nextInt();

    for (int t = 0; t < T; t++) {

        int N = input.nextInt();
        int[] A = new int[N];

        for (int n = 0; n < N; n++) {
            A[n] = input.nextInt();
        }

        if (N < 3) {
            System.out.println("-1");
        } else if (N == 3) {

            if (A[0] == A[2]) {
                System.out.println("1");
            } else {
                System.out.println("-1");
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println(getEquilibiriumPosition(A));
        }

    }
}

private static int getEquilibiriumPosition(int[] A) {

    int startPos = 0;
    int equilibriumPos = A.length - A.length / 2;
    int endPos = A.length - 1;

    int leftSum = A[startPos];
    int rightSum = A[endPos];

    for (int i = startPos + 1; i < equilibriumPos; i++) {
        leftSum += A[i];
    }

    for (int i = endPos - 1; i > equilibriumPos; i--) {
        rightSum += A[i];
    }

    if (leftSum > rightSum) {
        while (equilibriumPos != startPos) {
            if (leftSum == rightSum) {
                return equilibriumPos;
            }
            rightSum += A[equilibriumPos];
            equilibriumPos--;
            leftSum -= A[equilibriumPos];
        }
    } else if (leftSum < rightSum) {
        while (equilibriumPos != endPos) {
            if (leftSum == rightSum) {
                return equilibriumPos;
            }
            leftSum += A[equilibriumPos];
            equilibriumPos++;
            rightSum -= A[equilibriumPos];
        }
    } else {
        return equilibriumPos;
    }

    return -1;
}
```